# Maximum Independent Subset of 2D Grid Subgraph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

In the general case finding a Maximum Independent Subset of a Graph is NP-Hard.

However consider the following subset of graphs:

- Create an $N \times N$ grid of unit square cells.
- Build a graph $G$ by creating a vertex corresponding to every cell.  Notice that there are $N^2$ vertices.
- Create an edge between two vertices if their cells share a side.  Notice there are $2N(N-1)$ edges.

A Maximum Independent Subset of $G$ is obviously a checker pattern.  A cell at the $R$th row and $C$th column is part of it if $R+C$ is odd.

Now we create a graph $G'$ by copying $G$ and removing some vertices and edges.  (If you remove a vertex also remove all edges it ended of course. Also note you can remove an edge without removing one of the vertices it ends.)

By what algorithm can we find a Maximum Independent Subset of $G'$?

Comment: Hint: Grid graphs are bipartite.

Comment: @JeffE: There is one way to partition a grid graph into two sets of verticies such that they have no internal edge (by R+C parity).  Once you start removing verticies and edges doesn't the number of ways to partition it grow exponentially. (maybe I have it.  a single connected component maybe only still has one way to partition it)

Comment: Hint 2: Matching.

Comment: Yeah I think I see it.  Sort it into connected components.  Split each component into the unique two partition.  Select the larger partition from each component.

Comment: Nope.  The maximum independent set is not necessarily one side of the bipartition.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Example: G' = (A-B-C, B-E, D-E-F).  Bipartition (A,C,E | D,F,B).  Maximum Indep Set (A,C,D,F).

Comment: @JeffE: The Hopcroft–Karp algorithm finds a maximum set of edges such that none of them share an endpoint.  Maybe I can use that somehow.

Comment: @JeffE: I still haven't figured out how to get from a bipartite graph to a maximum independent set.  See my post [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/maximum-independent-set-of-a-bipartite-graph).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As JeffE mentions in a comment, a [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html) is an example of a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). If you take a bipartite graph, and remove some of the vertices, it will still be a bipartite graph.

[Königs Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) states, that for bipartite graphs, the number of vertices in a [minimum covering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover), equals the number of edges in a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching).

As mentioned in the answer for [Maximum Independent Set of a Bipartite Graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/maximum-independent-set-of-a-bipartite-graph):

> The complement of a maximum independent set is a minimum vertex
>   cover

What you are asking, is how to find a maximum independent set in a grid graph with some vertices removed, and the way to do that, is to use [some of the algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) for finding a maximum matching in a bipartite graph, from that construct a minimum vertex cover, and then invert it to get a maximum independent set.

The figure below shows a bipartite graph with a maximum matching (in blue), a minimum vertex cover (in red) and consequently also a maximum independent set (in white):

[image: from Wikipedias article on Königs Theorem]