# Library for Maximum independent set on a sparse bipartite graph (from sparse matrix)

Tags: graphs

I am working with sparse matrices (not particularly huge, <100Mb) and I want to compute the largest independent set on the bipartite graph $(N,E)$ defined as follows: suppose the matrix is named $A$ and is of size $m \times n$.

- $m+n$ nodes ($1,\dots,m$ for the rows, $m+1,\dots,m+n$ for the columns)
- the edge $(i,j) \in E \iff a_{ij} \neq 0$

An independent set is then a subset of rows and columns such that they "do not intersect".

The graph is clearly bipartite (edges are from the set $\{1,\dots,m\}$ to the set $\{m+1,\dots,m+n\}$), and therefore the computation of the largest independent set is definitely simpler than the general case (as suggested also [in this other question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/maximum-independent-set-of-a-bipartite-graph)).

This computation is not entirely critical for my work (my thesis, actually) so I would like to use as much code from existing libraries as possible. I tried [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/), but they use a general algorithm for the largest independent set (which is terribly slow for even a matrix of 5MB), and I have yet to try and see if doing explicitly all the passages "Maximum Matching > Minimum vertex cover > maximum independent set" helps (it depends on their implementation).

The fact that I have a bipartite graph definitely helps from the theoretical point of view, so bigger instances are solvable, but yet I have to find a nice library which might work well with big, sparse, bipartite graphs.

Do you know any other existing libraries to do this kind of job?

Comment: Maximum matchings are a standard part of numerical libraries, e.g. http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_manual/mcb_matching.html although I think you need to think of your sparse graph in terms of adjacency lists, not as a matrix.

Comment: The problem is that my starting point is a matrix, which can be viewed as the adjacency matrix for the graph constructed as in the post. The matrix is sparse and therefore not explicitly a matrix, but stored as a list of triplets $(i,j,value)$ (in this case the value is always 1).