# Algorithms or specific approaches for maximum independent set problem in triangle free graphs

Tags: graphs, approximation, heuristics

And obviously there will be no trivial vertex which has only 2 edges. I think triangle free graphs are (subjectively) easier than complicated graphs, i wonder if you know some heuristic approaches/steps specificly for triangle free graphs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Have you done any research?  e.g., searched with Google Scholar?  It's helpful to know what you've already done, so we don't repeat things you've already tried.

Comment: i haven't really searched specificly for triangle free graphs, i am now for about an hour. i am asking this question also as a starting point

Comment: If you're willing to consider not just triangle-free, but all odd-cycle free graphs then you get a very nice class of graphs - bipartite graphs. You can have a look at the discussion [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/maximum-independent-set-of-a-bipartite-graph?rq=1) for how to find a maximum independent set in Bipartite graphs